# craco build fails on compiling typescript file when run in a docker

Tags: typescript, docker, craco

I need to deploy a web application, built in react with typescript.
The deploy method is to build the docker image that runs nginx server that serves the static build and have it in the kubernetes container.

The build script is `craco build` and works correctly when run in the local terminal (macOS). Problem is when the same script is run in the docker image, then it returns the error:

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

./src/views/main/routeConfigs.ts
Syntax error: Unexpected token : (7:25)
```

The header of routeConfig.ts file is

```
import { vueCompsInReact } from '@console/legacy-v1/vueDMZ';
import { IRoute } from 'models/router.models';
import { wrapReactifiedVueComponent } from 'views/common/routing/wrapReactifiedVueComponent';
import { ROUTE_KEY } from '../routes';
import Home from './Home';

export const MAIN_ROUTES: IRoute<ROUTE_KEY>[] = [{
    routeKey: ROUTE_KEY.R_HOME,
    path: '/',
    exact: true,
    component: Home,
}, 
...
```

and the `Unexpected token : (7:25)` is the colon ':' in the line `export const MAIN_ROUTES: IRoute<ROUTE_KEY>[]`

What I do not understand is that it fails only in the docker.
The Dockerfile is:

```
FROM node:12-alpine as builder

# define PROJECT_PATH to project 
ENV PROJECT_PATH=packages/console-core
ENV V1_PATH=legacy-v1
ENV APP_ROOT=/console-v2

RUN node -v
RUN mkdir ${APP_ROOT}
WORKDIR ${APP_ROOT}
# copy root package to install dependencies
COPY .nvmrc .stylelintrc.js package.json package-lock.json lerna.json ./
# copy console core package
RUN mkdir ./packages
RUN mkdir ./${PROJECT_PATH}
COPY ${PROJECT_PATH}/package.json ${PROJECT_PATH}/package-lock.json ${PROJECT_PATH}/craco.config.js ./${PROJECT_PATH}/
# copy console v1 package
RUN mkdir ./${V1_PATH}
COPY ${V1_PATH}/package.json ${V1_PATH}/package-lock.json ./${V1_PATH}/
# install dependencies
RUN npm install 
RUN npx lerna bootstrap 

COPY ${V1_PATH} ./${V1_PATH}
COPY ${PROJECT_PATH} ./${PROJECT_PATH}

# RUN cd ${PROJECT_PATH}
WORKDIR ${PROJECT_PATH}

RUN npm run build
```

With command `RUN node -v` I can see that `node:12-alpine` image comes with node 12.18.3 version, while locally I have 12.14.0

The package.json file is

```
{
  "name": "@console/core",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "Core package of the web console",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "serve": "serve -s build",
    "test": "npm run lint && craco test --transformIgnorePatterns \"node_modules/(?!(@snipsonian))\"",
    "eslint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts,.tsx src",
    "stylelint": "stylelint src/**/*.scss",
    "lint": "npm run eslint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@console/legacy-v1": "^0.1.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@snipsonian/browser": "^1.12.0",
    "@snipsonian/core": "^1.11.0",
    "@snipsonian/dvlp": "^1.12.0",
    "@snipsonian/observable-state": "^1.12.0",
    "@snipsonian/react": "^1.12.0",
    "@snipsonian/react-observable-state": "^1.12.0",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "flat": "^5.0.0",
    "gsap": "^3.5.1",
    "history": "^5.0.0",
    "immer": "^7.0.1",
    "oidc-client": "^1.10.1",
    "ramda": "^0.27.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^5.6.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "@types/flat": "^5.0.1",
    "@types/history": "^4.7.6",
    "@types/jest": "^24.9.1",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.47",
    "@types/ramda": "^0.27.7",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.36",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.5",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^6.0.3",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^1.0.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "serve": "^11.3.2",
    "stylelint": "^13.6.0",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "winston": "^3.3.3",
    "yaml-loader": "^0.6.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all",
      "last 2 chrome version",
      "last 2 firefox version",
      "last 2 safari version",
      "not ie <= 11"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

The craco.config.js file is:

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
const { ESLINT_MODES, addBeforeLoader, loaderByName, getLoader } = require('@craco/craco');
const path = require('path');
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies
const StyleLintPlugin = require('stylelint-webpack-plugin');
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

const appSrc = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');
const imagesConsoleV1 = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../legacy-v1/public/img');

module.exports = {
    eslint: {
        mode: ESLINT_MODES.file,
    },
    webpack: {
        alias: {
            /**
             * Add the aliases for all the top-level folders in the `src/` folder.
             * In combination with tsconfig.pathsOverride.json
             * See https://resir014.xyz/posts/2019/03/13/using-typescript-absolute-paths-in-cra-20/
             */
            api: `${appSrc}/api/`,
            config: `${appSrc}/config/`,
            models: `${appSrc}/models/`,
            state: `${appSrc}/state/`,
            utils: `${appSrc}/utils/`,
            views: `${appSrc}/views/`,
        },
        plugins: [
            new VueLoaderPlugin(),
            new StyleLintPlugin({
                configBasedir: __dirname,
                context: appSrc,
                files: ['**/*.scss'],
            }),
            new CopyPlugin({
                patterns: [
                    {
                        from: imagesConsoleV1,
                        transformPath(targetPath) {
                            return `img/${targetPath}`;
                        },
                    },
                ],
            }),
        ],
        configure: (webpackConfig /* , { env, paths } */) => {
            // console.log('webpackConfig', JSON.stringify(webpackConfig));

            /**
             * Loader-execution-order is from bottom to top!
             * And from right to left!
             */

            /* making sure the file-loader does not handle the .vue files */
            const getFileLoaderResult = getLoader(
                webpackConfig,
                loaderByName('file-loader'),
            );
            if (getFileLoaderResult.isFound) {
                const { match } = getFileLoaderResult;
                // console.log('file-loader found', match.loader);
                // console.log(match.loader.exclude);

                /* orig value: exclude: [ /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/ ], */
                match.loader.exclude = [ /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx|vue)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/ ];
            }

            /* the yaml loader has to be placed 'before' (above) the file-loader
             * so that the yaml-loader is used on .yaml files instead of the file-loader (oneOf) */
            const yamlLoader = {
                test: /\.ya?ml$/,
                type: 'json', // Required by Webpack v4
                use: 'yaml-loader',
            };

            addBeforeLoader(webpackConfig, loaderByName('file-loader'), yamlLoader);

            /* adding the vue-loader
             * p.s. Doing it myself instead of "addBeforeLoader(webpackConfig, loaderByName('babel-loader'), vueLoader)"
             * because that adds the vueLoader inside te oneOf array instead of on the top-level.
             * Also "addAfterLoader" did not produce the expected behaviour. */
            // webpackConfig.resolve.alias['vue$'] = 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js';
            const vueLoader = {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
            };
            webpackConfig.module.rules.splice(0, 0, vueLoader); // adding it as the first element

            // console.log('webpackConfig.module', JSON.stringify(webpackConfig.module));

            return webpackConfig;
        },
    },
    jest: {
        configure: {
            moduleNameMapper: {
                /**
                 * Jest module mapper which will detect our absolute imports.
                 * In combination with tsconfig.pathsOverride.json
                 * See https://resir014.xyz/posts/2019/03/13/using-typescript-absolute-paths-in-cra-20/
                 */
                '^api(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/api$1',
                '^config(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/config$1',
                '^models(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/models$1',
                '^state(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/state$1',
                '^utils(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/utils$1',
                '^views(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/views$1',
                /**
                 * For the jest unit tests, we replace the vueDMZ (which serves as an entrypoint to the legacy v1 code)
                 * with a mock version, because otherwise jest has problems with the library imports in the legacy code
                 * (and problems with the vue code).
                 */
                '@console/legacy-v1/vueDMZ': '<rootDir>/../../legacy-v1/vueDMZ.jestMock',
            },
        },
    },
    babel: {
        plugins: [
            "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining",
        ],
    },
};
```

I am not web app expert and my question is what setting or locally enabled feature may be missing in the docker image, that is responsible for this error, which I understand is 'unable to parse latest typescript syntax'

Comment: I have the same issue, have you find a solution ?

Comment: Sorry @VincentMiquel I moved to another project and have no more access to check what was the solution